# Angular 2 Property Bindings Display `[object Object]`

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular

Good morning all,

I have a component called `CustomerAddressesEditComponent` that implements `OnInit`. In this class I'm declaring some properties like so;

```
address: CustomerAddressEdit;
title: string;
line1: string;
line2: string;
line3: string;
city: string;
region: string;
postcode: string;
country: string;
primary: string;
```

Then inside `ngOnInit()` I define each by calling a provided localisation service (`LOCALISATION_SOURCE` is a constant defined prior to the class declaration);

```
this.address = this._currentCustomerAddressService.getCurrentCustomerAddress();
this.title =            this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-TitleEdit", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.line1 =            this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Line1", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.line2 =            this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Line2", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.line3 =            this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Line3", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.city =             this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-City", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.region =           this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Region", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.postcode =         this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Postcode", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.country =          this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Country", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
this.primary =          this._localisationService.localise("Customer-Address-Edit-Form-Primary", LOCALISATION_SOURCE);
```

I then bind each of these (except title) to the `placeholder` attribute of the inputs on the template; (`address` is an object property that works fine)

```
<input type="text" id="txtAddr1" class="form-control" name="addr1" [(ngModel)]="address.addr1" #addr1="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="line1" />
<input type="text" id="txtAddr2" class="form-control" name="addr2" [(ngModel)]="address.addr2" #addr2="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="line2" />
<input type="text" id="txtAddr3" class="form-control" name="addr3" [(ngModel)]="address.addr3" #addr3="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="line3" />
<input type="text" id="txtPostcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" [(ngModel)]="address.postcode" #postcode="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="postcode" />
<input type="text" id="txtCity" class="form-control" name="city" [(ngModel)]="address.city" #city="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="city" />
<input type="text" id="txtRegion" class="form-control" name="region" [(ngModel)]="address.region" #region="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="region" />
<input type="text" id="txtCountry" class="form-control" name="country" [(ngModel)]="address.country" #country="ngModel" [attr.placeholder]="country" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbPrimaryAddress" name="primaryAddress" [(ngModel)]="address.primaryAddress" #primaryAddress="ngModel" /> {{primary}}
```

However the `city`, `region`, `postcode` and `country` properties all output `[object Object]` onto the page. I have also tried outputting them directly onto the page in double curly braces with the same result. The other properties all output just fine, not sure what's causing this problem.

In `ngOnInit()` I logged these failing properties to the console before definition, which printed `undefined` yet when logging after the definition the correct values were printed which were supplied by the localisation service - so I don't know why these values are not appearing on the template.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please - is this a lifecycle issue potentially?

**Update - Localisation Signature**

```
export class LocalisationService extends ApplicationService {
    ...
    localise(key: string, sourceName: string): string {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update - Address property type**

```
export class CustomerAddressEdit extends Address {
    customerId: number;
    customer: CustomerEdit;

    primaryAddress: boolean;
}

export class Address extends AuditedEntity {
    addressTypeId: number;
    addressType: AddressType;

    addr1: string;
    addr2: string;
    addr3: string;
    city: string;
    region: string;
    postcode: string;
    country: string;
    geoLocation: any;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the signature of the `localisationService.localise` method?

Comment: Sorry, which part is the signature please? I probably should have mentioned that I'm fairly new to Angular 2.

Comment: `public foo(bla:string):string` <-This is the signature part.

Comment: Thanks - see post update. It should be noted that this does work as expected - when I use `console.log(this.city)` for example the correct string does get outputted.

Comment: I think you should also add the model class for address, I think it's a typing problem in address object.

Comment: Added - I'm not going to add every extended class, that would take all day haha! I know these models work because they're used elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Well, if your form is displaying `[Object object]`, that's because your property is an object, even if console.log works fine. So the problem should be in one of the classes extending `Address`.

Comment: Stepping through the entire `localise()` function returns a string, and the string is assigned to the `city` property. It just doesn't appear to display this. Also these properties are unrelated to the address object - they just have similar names to the address objects properties.